# How do I find an item in a JList and set that as the selected value?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

When I update the JList, I want to keep the selection of what it was before updating the JList. When updating a JList, it can either remove an object or add an object.

This is what I have right now:

```
Object obj = list.getSelectedValue(); // This is line 47
list.clearSelection();
list.setListData(peerList);

if(obj != null)
{
   int selectedIndex = list.getNextMatch(obj.toString(), 0, Position.Bias.Forward);

   if(selectedIndex != -1)
      list.setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);
   else
      list.clearSelection();
}
```

But then sometimes, when an object is added or removed, it would throw an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 3
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JList$5.getElementAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JList.getSelectedValue(Unknown Source)
    at MyThread$1.run(MyThread.java:47) // I marked up top where line 47 is
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I will consider that next time, but I was able to figure it out. Thanks though.

Comment: No problem.  All in good time. :)

Comment: please whats `Position.Bias.Forward` somehow usefull in `JList`, whats reason, can you please elaborate ...

Comment: @mKorbel From what I understood, when it searches each element, Position.Bias.Forward is specifying what direction to search the string. For example, "Hello World", and you're looking for "orl", if you specify Position.Bias.Backwards, I'm assuming you start searching the string from the end. Again, this is all assumption, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getNextMatch%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.text.Position.Bias%29

Comment: then to use Filtering/ Sorting / highlighting(renderer) in JTable, one column without JTableHeader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was. `peerList` is a Vector, so before this I do the adding and deleting of elements from the Vector, not the JList, though I don't know if this is possible. So if I deleted an object from the Vector and I asked to get the selected value from a JList before updating it, it wouldn't be able to find it. But the JList would still show the deleted element until you use `setListData` and update the JList.

Answer (score 3):

That seems to me like a concurrency issue. Are you updating the selection index and removing/adding elements all on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), or are you running concurrent threads that do this? You should only change the selection or modify the list on the EDT.

Comment: I was modifying the list on the EDT, but it was in a `Runnable`, which I used `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable)`, to invoke it, would that have caused any issues? But I was able to figure out what was wrong, I posted my solution in an edit in my original post.

Comment: Using 'invokeLater' is usually the right thing to do. Perhaps it was not a concurrency error in your case, but many coders eventually do the mistake of modifying things outside of the EDT and then end up with similar-looking errors.

You should approve your own answer by the way so that others can see what the solution was quicker.